# Image with multiple axes of symmetry

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called to mirror a 2D object / image both vertically and horizontally? Or is this still just referred to as being *symmetric*?

See the following game map; the engine only needs to generate 1/4 of the map and will then mirror it to make the game fair for all 4 players.

[image]

Is there a specific name for this kind of symmetry which is along more then a single axis?

*The map is [symmetric] meaning that it is equal for all 4 players.*

Comment: I should probably point out that none of the four corners of the picture you provided are exact mirror images of any of the other corners—so, it's actually a poor illustration . . .

Comment: Sorry, the asset images are different, but the actual map structure is a mirror image. Bushes in one area may be rocks or logs in another. It is a poor illusion yes, but it is what I was initially trying to describe when posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

In two dimentions there are, effectively, two types of symmetry, reflectional and rotational.

In reflectional symmetry you imagine a flat mirror being placed on a line through the middle of the graphic and the half of the original combined with the reflection being indistinguisable from the entire original. If you could place the mirror on more than one line the image has *multiple axes of reflextional symmetry*.

Some graphics do not have reflectional symmetry but do have rotational symmetry. In this case if the image is rotated around its centre and there is at least one partial rotation following which the graphic is indistinguishable from its original position the graphic has rotational symmetry. The size of the angle through which the graphic needs to be turned, and therefore the more times in one rotation it displays rotational symmetry, determines the *order* of its rotational symmetry. If you can only turn it through 180° then it has rotational symmetry of order 2, through 90° has order 4 and so on.

Your graphic has 2 axes of reflectional symmetry (vertical and horizontal) but has only rotational symmetry of order 2 because of the long feature in the centre, the spaces at top and bottom and other features. Some graphics have reflectional symmetry but not rotational symmetry (the upper case letter T for example) while others have rotational symmetry but not reflectional symmetry (the letters S and Z for example).

The reason you only have to create a quarter of the graphic is that a vertical or horizontal reflection creates half of the full graphic and the other relection creates the othrr half.

Answer (score 0):

It is of course, still symmetric. Only that it's symmetrical about more than one plane.

Technically, it may be said to be **polysymmetrical**, or symmetrical about *n* planes/axes.

Flowers often have a polysymmetrical arrangement.

Crystals too exhibit polysymmetry.

Polysymmetry is an important aspect in mathematics.

Comment: Botany uses *zygomorphic* for having a single axis of symmetry, and *actinomorphic* for multiple axes in the same plane.